# js code works for one variable(?), how to make it work for many?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selector

I have working code of js, it shows different div for selected option.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#box1').hide();
$('#box2').hide();
$('#box3').hide();
$("#thechoices").change(function(){
$("#" + this.value).show().siblings().hide();
});    
$("#thechoices").change();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<select id="thechoices">
<option value="box1">Box 1</option>
<option value="box2">Box 2</option>
<option value="box3">Box 3</option>
</select>

<!-- the DIVs -->
<div id="boxes">
<div id="box1"><p>Box 1 stuff...</p></div>
<div id="box2"><p>Box 2 stuff...</p></div>
<div id="box3"><p>Box 3 stuff...</p></div>
</div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Please, I have no js experience, so I don't know how to make it work several times on one page for many "thechoices". Something like copy paste but more suitable than this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#box1').hide();
$('#box2').hide();
$('#box3').hide();

$('#box4').hide();
$('#box5').hide();
$('#box6').hide();
$("#thechoices").change(function(){
$("#" + this.value).show().siblings().hide();
});
$("#thechoices2").change(function(){
$("#" + this.value).show().siblings().hide();
});

$("#thechoices").change();
});
$("#thechoices2").change();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<select id="thechoices">
<option value="box1">Box 1</option>
<option value="box2">Box 2</option>
<option value="box3">Box 3</option>
</select>

<!-- the DIVs -->
<div id="boxes">
<div id="box1"><p>Box 1 stuff...</p></div>
<div id="box2"><p>Box 2 stuff...</p></div>
<div id="box3"><p>Box 3 stuff...</p></div>
</div>

<select id="thechoices2">
<option value="box4">1</option>
<option value="box5">2</option>
<option value="box6">3</option>
</select>

<!-- the DIVs -->
<div id="boxes">
<div id="box4"><p>1 stuff...</p></div>
<div id="box5"><p>2 stuff...</p></div>
<div id="box6"><p>3 stuff...</p></div>
</div>
```

I know you can help me, it seems to be simple but I can't handle with this.
How can I change my second code to work in the same way but not only for two selectors. I need it for many. Don't want to copy paste the same section like in my second code.

Comment: so what is the problem ?

Comment: I just don't want to create large file with thechoices1... thechoices100, I want to make it dynamic.

Comment: don't use IDs but a single class

Comment: Oh, it means that I should replace $('#box1').hide();
$('#box2').hide();...
only with class .box, and add this class to my every div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your code a little bit. Check this one:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.boxes div').hide();

$(".thechoices").change(function(){
var id = $(this).attr("id").replace("thechoices_", "");
var value = parseInt($(this).val());
$("#boxes_" + id + " div:eq(" + (value -1) + ")").show().siblings().hide();
});

$(".thechoices").change();

});
</script>

<select class="thechoices" id="thechoices_1">
<option value="1">Box 1</option>
<option value="2">Box 2</option>
<option value="3">Box 3</option>
</select>

<!-- the DIVs -->
<div class="boxes" id="boxes_1">
<div><p>Box 1 stuff...</p></div>
<div><p>Box 2 stuff...</p></div>
<div><p>Box 3 stuff...</p></div>
</div>

<select class="thechoices" id="thechoices_2">
<option value="1">Box 1</option>
<option value="2">Box 2</option>
<option value="3">Box 3</option>
</select>

<!-- the DIVs -->
<div class="boxes" id="boxes_2">
<div><p>Box 1 stuff...</p></div>
<div><p>Box 2 stuff...</p></div>
<div><p>Box 3 stuff...</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice idea, but it shows me all 3 boxes under all selectors. Doesn't matter what I select, nothing changed - 3 options are still visible.

Comment: There was a syntax error and I have modified the code. Please Try again :)

Comment: I have a question - how can I make my <option> thechoices reset to view the first value after refresh the page? It shows me last remembered position before refreshment but the value (from php) is being taken as value="1", what is desired.

Comment: after this line: `$('.boxes div').hide();` you add this line: `$(".thechoices").val("1");` I think this should work. BTW, are you testing it on Firefox?

Comment: yes, ff is my main browser, but after adding new java I am testing site on chrome and ie too.
thanks once again, val(1) helped:)

Comment: you're welcome again :) happy coding!!

Answer (score 1):

Avoid repeating IDs and provide a means for each select menu to address its corresponding boxes.

In the HTML:

- change `id="thechoices"` to `class="thechoices"`
- change `id="boxn"` to `class="boxn"` all through
- wrap each select and its corresponding boxes in `<div class="boxWrapper">...</div>`

Now use the following jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".thechoices").change(function(){
        $this = $(this);
        $this.closest(".boxWrapper").find("." + $this.val()).show().siblings().hide();
    }).change();
});
```

Be sure to use `$this.val()` and not `this.value` for cross browser reliability.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work, the problem is that before I am making a choose there is no div visible, after select option I can see selected div but only in first step, the second selector still shows all 3 divs.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the (main) point about multiple selects etc. Answer edited accordingly.

Comment: Still not there - one moment ....

Comment: I would do a fiddle demo but I need to be somewhere like minutes ago.

Comment: Just to prove it works, here's [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SYnfu/)

Answer (score 0):

This will run on any `select` tag:

```
$("select").change(function(){
    $("#" + this.value).show().siblings().hide();
});
```